# OpenGeo Suite installed on Ubuntu 14.04, unable to proceed/delete issues with dependencies

Tags: geoserver, error, ubuntu, boundless-suite, tomcat

I have installed the OpenGeo Suite on my "Trusty Tahr". I am able to access my Tomcat server as well as Geoserver on http://localhost.

[image]

[image]

The issue I'm dealing with currently stems from dependencies related PostGIS and PostgreSQL versions that didn't install properly. [image]

As a result I am unable to install any additional applications nor have all my dependencies updated as such.
[image]

I have tried several methods from trying to remove the applications at issue through the Software Center
[image],

I've attempted running apt-get install -f as well as other troubleshooting techniques that I found search through the web.
[image]

Any thoughts how to rectify this?

Comment: I thought OpenGeo Suite gives you the option to install all the other apps, openlayers, postgresql, ....etc.  Did you not install those through the installer?

Comment: I did install all of the other applications that is included in the suite. I followed the steps outlined on their [website](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/intro/installation/ubuntu/install.html#intro-installation-ubuntu-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to resolve the dependency issue through installation of the missing dependency individually. That proved to not be the solution and after several iteration I realized there was a loop of dependencies that would update because it was dependent on another installation. After exhausting methods I found through forums and other resources. I ended up uninstalling 14.04 and reinstalling the entire OS, and eventually OpenGEO Suite. Everything installed correctly and now is up and running normally.